# AbstractModel and override save method in django

Tags: django, django-models

A lot of examples of save() methods are mentioned in StackOverflow. This is my idea: Model is abstract.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # take id of 'self' object by: last id + 1 or 1 if there is no objects in db 
    try:
        future_id = int(self.__class__.objects.latest('pk').pk) + 1
    except:
        future_id = 1

    # set slug by id     
    self.slug = '{future_id}'.format(future_id=future_id)

    # set slug by name and id
    if self.get_name():
        self.slug = '{name}-{slug}'.format(name=slugify(self.get_name()), 
                                           slug=self.slug)
    # save        
    super(AbstractCmsContent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The question is: should I prepare some general table in database with last id or  this solution with latest() function calling should work well in practice?

### Added:

I will answer how I changed this function. At the end my function looks like this:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.slug:

            self.slug = '{name}'.format(name=slugify(self.get_name())) 

            objs = self.__class__.objects.filter(slug__startswith=self.slug)
            max_index = objs.aggregate(Max('slug_index'))['slug_index__max']

            # two conditions: 
            # max_index should be positive, 
            # or number of objects with simillar slug in db > 0
            if max_index or objs.count()>0:
                self.slug_index = max_index + 1
                self.slug = "{slug}-{index}".format(slug=self.slug,
                                                index=self.slug_index)

        super(AbstractCmsContent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

First slug is always based only on name, and next one has some extra index: 'slug-index'. Also I added some extra field slug_index to my model, but like this I have quiet good control over my slugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you should not rely on getting latest id like this because some day you will either face race condition (when your latest pk will be already taken) or some of your models will get wrong ids.

I would suggest to make slug field nullable (and it's the only option if it has something like `unique=True`) and populate it after `super` call. Thus you will get bulletproof reliable id and simplify your code by delegating all the stuff to the database. Also if you use modern DB it will all happen in transaction so there will not be any time when your object does not have slug.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AbstractCmsContent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.slug = '{pk}'.format(pk=self.pk)
    if self.get_name():
        self.slug = '{name}-{slug}'.format(name=slugify(self.get_name()), slug=self.slug)
    self.__class__.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(slug=self.slug)
```

Comment: Thanks, good point about lasted(), I didn't trust my solution, so is good to listen this opinion from you.  I am thinking, if I understand good save() method, if you will call super(...).save() at the beginning, where is the logic which is saving this new slug field?

Comment: I have tested your answer, but unfortunately is not working. If you call super().save() before logic with slug, the object will have new slug but this change will not appear in database, so this change will not be permanent.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I've forgotten the last part. Answer updated.

Comment: Yes, now is working:) at the end my function looks little bit different.. I decided that first slug will be always based only on name, and if is repeted I will add some extra index. Answer with code below.